# laravel polymorphic relation assign model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a polymorphic relation

```
codes (code, soure_id, source_type)
```

sources:

```
websites (id, url)

books (id, isbn)
```

I have the necessary relations (morphTo, morphMany) coded in the models.

How can I assign a source to a code:

```
$source = Book::first();

    $code = new Code()
    $code->code = 'huxawex123ad'
    $code->source ... // How can I assign the book as the source?
    $code->save();
```

relations:

```
class Code extends Eloquent {
    public function source()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
};

class Book extends Eloquent {
    public function codes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Code::class, 'source');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`MorphTo` relationships are similar to `BelongsTo` relationships. So, assuming your `Code` model has a `source()` method setup to return a `morphTo()` relationship, your code would look like:

```
$source = Book::first();

$code = new Code()
$code->code = 'huxawex123ad'
$code->source()->associate($source);
$code->save();
```

Additionally, assuming your `Book` model had a `codes()` method setup to return a `morphMany()` relationship, your code could clean up like so:

```
$source = Book::first();

$source->codes()->create(['code' => 'huxawex123ad']);
```

Comment: The problem is, that the code row already exists. I need to add the relationship instead of creating a new code entry.

Comment: And associate fails with: Class 'voluptates' not found... Even though the class should be App\Models\Book

Comment: this line help me $code->source()->associate($source);

Answer (score 2):

I dont's see proper fields set for polymorphic relationships

Add these fields to codes table:

```
sourceable_id - integer
sourceable_type - string
```

Relationships would be like:

```
 class website extends Model
 {
  /**
  * Get all of the website's codes.
  */
  public function codes()
  {
     return $this->morphMany('App\Code', 'sourceable');
  }
}
```

Then in your controllers:

```
$source = Book::first();

$code = new Code()
$code->code = 'huxawex123ad'
$code->source ... // How can I assign the book as the source?
$code->save();

$source->codes()->save($code);
```

Comment: That's what I have. I am missing the line: $code->source ... // How can I assign the book as the source?